# Insert Into from VBA - Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to push through an Insert into statement from my Access DB to the sql server. This has been working but i needed to make changes to how i wrote column "j" as i need to now differentiate between true  and NULL. I keep getting the error "Invalid use of null". How should I cast Column J's portion to avoid this error?

```
                              If trow = 0 Then
                               Sql = "INSERT ALL "
                               Sql = Sql + Chr(10) + "INTO " + username + "." + dbtable + " VALUES (" + _
                                    "q'[" + Format(rstIn("a"), "dd-mmm-yy") + "]'," + _
                                    "q'[" + Nz(rstIn("b"), "UNKNOWN") + "]'," + _
                                       "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("c"), "0")) + "," + _
                                    "q'[" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("d"), "UNKNOWN")) + "]'," + _
                                    "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("f"), "0")) + "," + _
                                    "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("e"), "0")) + "," + _
                                    "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("g"), "0")) + "," + _
                                    "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("h"), "0")) + "," + _
                                    "q'[" + Nz(rstIn("i"), "UNKNOWN") + "]'," + _
                                    "q'[" + Format(rstIn("z"), "dd-mmm-yy") + "]'," + _
                                    "" + (rstIn("j").Value) + "," + _
                                    "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("k"), "0")) + "," + _
                                    "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("l"), "0")) + "," + _
                                    "" + CStr(Nz(rstIn("m"), "0")) + _
                                    ")"
```

Comment: Try `Nz(rstIn("j").Value, vbNullString)`.

Comment: This may be a  step in the right direction. The error moved from invalid null to type mismatch. This column is numerical, but it does allow null values

Comment: For a record with a null value try doing a print of the SQL so we can see what exactly is generated.

Comment: Why build an SQL query in code with messy concatenation and punctuation? Is the SQL Server table a linked table in Access database? What is the `q'` prefix?

Answer (score 1):

If `j` is a numeric field, you cannot pass a string to it. So, if *Null* is not accepted, try a true zero:

```
"" + Nz(rstIn("j").Value, 0) + "," + _
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you connect to SQL Server with [ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/microsoft-activex-data-objects-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) in MS Access VBA, consider a parameterized solution that avoids messy data concatenation and quote punctuation. You can even define [data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum?view=sql-server-ver15) of parameters with `adVarChar`, `adDate`, `adInteger`, etc.

Below shows a looped version iterating through an Access recordset to execute insert-values queries into SQL Server connection. Parameters are defined for first 5 for demonstration to be extended for all 14. Adjust column names and anywhere abbreviated with `...`.

```vb
Dim sql As String
Dim connection As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rstIn As DAO.Recordset

' OPEN ACCESS LOCAL RECORDSET
Set rstIn = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT a, b, c, d, e, ... FROM myAccessTable")

' PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA) WITH ? PLACEHOLDERS
sql = "INSERT INTO [" & username & "].[" & dbtable &] "(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, " _ 
       & "                                              COl6, COl7, COL8, COL9, COL10, " _
       & "                                              COL11, COL12, COl13, COl14)" _
       & " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

' OPEN EXTERNAL SQL SERVER CONNECTION
Set connection = New ADODB.Connection
connection.Open "..."

Do While Not rstIn.EOF
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command       ' INITIALIZE COMMAND

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = connection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = query

        ' BIND PARAMETERS
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , rstIn("a"))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Nz(rstIn("b"), "UNKNOWN"))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDouble, adParamInput, , Nz(rstIn("c"), "0"))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Nz(rstIn("d"), "UNKNOWN"))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDouble, adParamInput, , Nz(rstIn("f"), "0"))
        ...

        ' RUN QUERY
        .Execute
    End With

    Set cmd = Nothing                 ' RELEASE COMMAND
    rstIn.MoveNext
Loop

rstIn.Close: connection.Close
Set rstIn = Nothing: Set connection = Nothing
```

---

Alternatively, if you can [link SQL Server table in MS Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-sql-server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e), a simpler insert-select query can work, avoiding loops and one line of VBA.

**SQL** *(save as stored query)*

```sql
INSERT INTO mySQLServerLinkedTable (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, 
                                    COl6, COl7, COL8, COL9, COL10,                                              
                                    COL11, COL12, COl13, COl14)
SELECT Format(a, "dd-mmm-yy"), Nz(b, "UNKNOWN"), CStr(Nz(c, "0")), 
       CStr(Nz(d, "UNKNOWN")), CStr(Nz(f, "0")), CStr(Nz(e, "0")), 
       CStr(Nz(g, "0")), CStr(Nz(h, "0")), Nz(i, "UNKNOWN"),
       Format(z, "dd-mmm-yy"), j, CStr(Nz(k, "0")), 
       CStr(Nz(l, "0")), CStr(Nz(m, "0")))
FROM myAccessLocalTable
```

**VBA**

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedInsertQuery"
```